# SQLite database is locked C# after update?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have the following code, that makes update query:

```
public void update(ClientResponse client)
        {
            db.ExecuteScalar("UPDATE PacientsOrder SET status = '"+client.status+"' WHERE pacient_id = '" + client.pacient_id + "' AND kind_work = '" + client.kind_work + "'"); // 222 Line
            db.ExecuteScalar("UPDATE Transactions SET http_code = '" + client.http_code+ "' WHERE pacient_id = '" + client.pacient_id+"'");
        }
```

Where `ExecuteScalar` is method of Db connector:

```
public string ExecuteScalar(string sql)
        {
            SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection); // 119 line
            cnn.Open();
            SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(cnn);
            mycommand.CommandText = sql;
            object value = mycommand.ExecuteScalar();
            cnn.Close();
            if (value != null)
            {
                return value.ToString();
            }
            return "";
        }
```

When I try to perform queries mentioned above I get an error:

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException (0x80004005): database is locked
database is locked
   в System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Step(SQLiteStatement stmt)
   в System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
   в System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
   в System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   в System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteScalar(CommandBehavior behavior)
   в System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteScalar()
   в SQLiteDatabase.ExecuteScalar(String sql) в D:\Projects\Library\SQLiteDatabase.cs:строка 119
   Pacients.update(ClientResponse client) в D:\Projects\c-tests-u Controllers\Pacients\Pacients.cs:строка 222
```

I can not understand a reason of this error.

Thissi s my Delete method:

```
public bool Delete(String tableName, String where)
        {
            Boolean returnCode = true;
            try
            {
                this.ExecuteNonQuery(String.Format("delete from {0} where {1};", tableName, where));
            }
            catch (Exception fail)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(fail.Message);
                returnCode = false;
            }
            return returnCode;
        }
```

Updated SQL delete method:

```
public bool Delete(String tableName, String where)
        {

            string sql = String.Format("delete from {0} where {1};", tableName, where);

            using (SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection))
            using (SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(sql, cnn))
            {
                cnn.Open();
                object value = mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return (value != null) ? value.ToString() : "";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Not disposing your `mycommand` is probably the reason.

Comment: ...as was explained the last time you asked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disposable objects like the SQLiteCommand but in particular the SQLiteConnection should be disposed as soon as possible. To facilitate this pattern the *[using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)* should be used around these objects

```
public string ExecuteScalar(string sql)
{
    using(SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection))
    using(SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(sql, cnn))
    {
        cnn.Open();
        object value = mycommand.ExecuteScalar();
        return (value != null ? value.ToString() : "";
    }
}
```

A part from this I suggest you to name this method ExecuteNonQuery instead of ExecuteScalar and call the SQLiteCommand ExecuteNonQuery.   ExecuteScalar has a different meaning and using it for UPDATE operations is confusing

Comment: What's difference corresponding my code? Do you recommend to substitute whole method?

Comment: Where connection `cnn` is closed?

Comment: It is automatically closed when code exits from the closing brace of the using block. Using Statement is an elegant way to replace _try...finally_ the finally block contains the dispose of the object created in the using starting line. In case of DbConnection the dispose method calls the Close method. So your connection is always closed also in case of exceptions.

Comment: The dispose call at the exit from the using block will close and then release any lock kept on your database file. After this, you should not have any pending lock on it. Of course I cannot see all of your code, but this pattern, if used regularly, guarantees proper handling of your database file.

Comment: Why do you recommend to use this method only for updating?

Comment: Can I use this code instead delete methods(see question)

Comment: ExecuteScalar is used when you want to retrieve a single value like the result of SUM or COUNT or a SELECt with only one record and one column. ExecuteNonQuery is used when you run UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE or other DDL commands

Comment: Can you share an example how to use `ExecuteNonQuery` right? is it the same?

Comment: Well, your Delete method uses the ExecuteNonQuery correctly, albeit you have a big problem with string concatenation instead of parameters. But this is a different story.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158237/discussion-between-steve-and-opv).